# What scheme is used to encode unicode characters in a .url shortcut?

Tags: url, unicode-string, shortcut-file

What scheme is used to encode unicode characters in a windows url shortcut?

For example, a new shortcut for url "[http://Ψαℕ](http://%CE%A8%CE%B1%E2%84%95)℧▶" produces a .url file with the text:

---

[{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]

Prop3=19,2

[InternetShortcut]

IDList=

URL=http://?aN??/

[InternetShortcut.A]

URL=http://?aN??/

[InternetShortcut.W]

URL=http://+A6gDsSEVIScltg-/

---

What is the algorithm to decode "+A6gDsSEVIScltg-" to "Ψαℕ℧▶"?

I am not asking for API code, but I would like to know the encoding scheme details.

Note: The encoding scheme is not utf-8 nor utf-16 nor ucs-2 and no %encoding.

Answer (score 1):

`+A6gDsSEVIScltg-` is the [**UTF-7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7) encoded form of `Ψαℕ℧▶`.

The *correct* way to process a `.url` file is to use the `IUniformResourceLocator` and `IPropertyStorage` interfaces from the `CLSID_InternetShortcut` COM object.  See [Internet Shortcuts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/internet-shortcuts) on MSDN for details.

Answer (score 0):

The answer (utf-7) allowed me to successfully develop the url conversion routine.

Let me summarize the steps:

To obtain the unicode url from a InternetShortcut.W found in a .url file.

. Pass ascii chars until crlf, after making them internet safe.

. A none escaped  + character starts a utf-7 formatted unicode sequence:

.  Collect 6-bit nibbles from base64 coded ascii

. Per collected 16 bits, convert the 16 bits to utf-8 (1,2, or 3 chars)

. Pass the utf8 generated characters as %hh

.  Continue until the occurrence of a "-" character

. The bit collector should be zero